# Is it possible to execute a function or procedures concurrently in SQL

Tags: sql, parallel-processing

```
Update A set data=FUNCTION(Id,formula) from temptable
```

In the above query I am not sure whether it is parallel execution or sequence execution. Please explain.

Comment: Not all RDBMSs support parallelism. Which SQL server will this be running on?

Comment: SQL server 2008 R2